# Npm install process is looking for NVM folder

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I recently completely uninstalled NVM from my computer.
Now when trying to install IONIC with "npm install -g @ionic/cli", the process try to use a folder from the old NVM installation.

```
>npm install -g @ionic/cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist** ---> Is not existing anymore

The npm instalaction folder is:

`npm@7.0.3 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`

Comment: Please re install Nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was running the following command:

`npm config delete prefix`

There was a nodist installation and I had not done the complete uninstallation steps.

Answer (score 0):

Check PATH in System->Advanced System Settings-> Environment variables